# What's the right punctuation (and why) for the phrase, "You're holding my hand Chuck you sly dog"

Tags: punctuation

It's a phrase from Peanuts, said by Peppermint Pat whenever Charlie Brown touched her appendage.

> "You're holding my hand Chuck you sly dog"

I've seen it punctuated several different ways. What is the right way to punctuate this phrase, and why?

Comment: What 'different ways'?

Answer (score 1):

Like this:
*"You're holding my hand, Chuck, you sly dog."*

The commas before and after the name *Chuck* are required because it is a term of direct address in the middle of a sentence. The phrase *you sly dog* is another joking form of address in apposition to *Chuck*.

The first answer to a slightly different question gives some more examples of commas with direct address:
[ELU stack exchange *comma placement*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471961/comma-placement-after-greeting-and-a-term-of-endearment)

It's not normal to refer to part of a human as an *appendage*, unless you are making some kind of joke.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single "correct" way. The punctuation is there to indicate how Patty speaks, and she might say this in different ways.  She could speak this as a single sentence

> You're holding my hand, Chuck, you sly dog.

Or she might express surprise:

> You're holding my hand!  Chuck, you sly dog.

(The second part isn't grammatically a sentence, but this is speech and such fragments are normal.)

Or she might break over two utterances, and whisper but exclaim the second part.

> You're holding my hand, Chuck. {something happens} *You sly dog!*

Hell, we could get creative and include some "scare quotes" and a rhetorical question

> You're "holding" my hand?  Chuck, you sly dog!